# How to launch my app programmatically, if an other app opens?  

Tags: cocoa, macos, launch

I want, that my app opens when (for example) the user opens iTunes. How Can I do this?

Comment: Assume you're talking about the Mac here?

Comment: Hopefully not - unless your application is so stellar and exceptionally that it should always do. And I don't think it is - if the user doesn't want your application to start, then it is the last word.

Comment: I am talking about Mac OS - Sorry for the confusion. I'm writing a Last.fm scrobbler and it should always opens, if iTunes opens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a program always running in the background that is subscribed to NSWorkspace's NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification and have it do its thing when it sees iTunes as the NSWorkspaceApplicationKey object.

Comment: The first part of your sentence first suggested polling until I realized you meant to register as an observer for a notification. I was momentarily horrified at what seemed to be a very un-Chuck-like answer. ;-)

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi: Ah, it did kind of read that way. Fixed — thanks for that.

Comment: It was like one of those slow-motion moments. I reached for the keyboard, as if through molasses, yelling "Nnnnnnoooooooo!!!!" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking iOS; you can't.